# Automate zoho grant token generation or code generation, without using self client code directly

Tags: node.js, api, axios, zoho, zohobooks

I am using this url `https://accounts.zoho.in/oauth/v2/auth?scope=ZohoInvoice.invoices.CREATE&client_id=1000.G1NT1HEKCZB7TACFBW7TRD3PX0WHxxX&state=testing&response_type=code&access_type=offline&prompt=Consent` as mentioned in this docs, but this is redirecting me to a new url where iam asked to click on the accept( this step i want it to be done in backend itself instead of doing it in browser) then it redirects us to the url which has code in it.

Comment: In the Zoho API Console did you choose client application?

Comment: If you don't mind, why do you want to automate it? Once you generate an access and refresh token, you won't need it again.

Answer (score 2):

You should use Self-Client to generate the Client API keys.
This would allow you to be used on the backend.

https://api-console.zoho.in/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).